# Where to find golang modules?

Tags: go, module, go-modules

I am from node.js ecosystem.

Golang has released its module system finally and I have read some articles about it:

- https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules
- https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

But, after that, I still didn't find a place like npmjs.com where I can find available go modules.

Comment: The whole point is to _not_ have a central repository.

Comment: Use Google to find Go modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no central repository *yet*, but note that the module support is still experimental in Go 1.12. It will be enabled by default in Go 1.13 (scheduled for August 2019).

Check out [The Go Blog: Go Modules in 2019](https://blog.golang.org/modules2019).

> For publicly-available modules, we intend to run a service we call a *notary* that follows the module index log, downloads new modules, and cryptographically signs statements of the form “module M at version V has file tree hash H.” The notary service will publish all these notarized hashes in a queryable, [Certificate Transparency](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/)-style [tamper-proof log](http://static.usenix.org/event/sec09/tech/full_papers/crosby.pdf), so that anyone can verify that the notary is behaving correctly. This log will serve as a public, global `go.sum` file that `go get` can use to authenticate modules when adding or updating dependencies.
>
> We are aiming to have the go command check notarized hashes for publicly-available modules not already in `go.sum` starting in Go 1.13.

and

> ### Module Discovery
>
> Finally, we mentioned earlier that the module index will make it easier to build sites like godoc.org. Part of our work in 2019 will be a major revamp of godoc.org to make it more useful for developers who need to discover available modules and then decide whether to rely on a given module or not.
>
> ### Big Picture
>
> This diagram shows how module source code moves through the design in this post.
>
> [image]

Comment: That's all about trust though, not about having a central repository for finding modules like npm.org.

Comment: @Adrian The notary, yes, but `godoc.org` will be something like that: _"Part of our work in 2019 will be a major revamp of godoc.org to make it more useful for developers who need to discover available modules and then decide whether to rely on a given module or not."_

Answer (score 5):

There is no central repository for Go modules. As long as you follow the conventions for publishing Go packages (see [PackagePublishing](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackagePublishing)), the go tools will be able to fetch your package/module, no matter where you published it.

In order to discover what is already out there in the Go universe, a good starting point is [Awesome Go](https://awesome-go.com/), a curated list of awesome Go packages/modules.

Answer (score 5):

https://search.gocenter.io can be used to search for Go modules, know more about popularity of a module version and even help module authors connect with their consumers. This is GA since end of January 2019 and globally available.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. If you start off with the built-in packages (https://golang.org/pkg/), and you follow some non-obvious links, you eventually end up here:

https://pkg.go.dev/